# String extension that adds a method "add" and takes an Int as a parameter with no label and returns an optional Int

Tags: swift

I am trying to do string extension that adds a method "add" and takes an Int as a parameter with no label and returns an optional Int. If the string can be turned into an integer, return an integer with the string’s integer value plus the passed in value. If the string cannot be turned into an integer, return nil.

I wrote out the code below however I can't get it to work.

I get the following warning message for each value:

> Immutable value 'value1' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it

---

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() { 
        let value1: Int? = "5".add(3) // value1 will equal 8
        let value2: Int? = "-2".add(1) // value2 will equal -1
        let value3: Int? = "words".add(4) // value3 will be nil
    }
}
```

---

```
extension String {   
    func add(_: Int) -> Int? {
        guard let someString = Int(self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return someString + someString
    }
}
```

---

This is what the solution is supposed to be:

```
let value1: Int? = "5".add(3) // value1 will equal 8
let value2: Int? = "-2".add(1) // value2 will equal -1
let value3: Int? = "words".add(4) // value3 will be nil
```

Comment: What does "I can't get it to work" mean?

Comment: This is the following error I get for each value: Immutable value 'value1' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it.

Comment: Swift is saying, you never use `value1` after defining it, so why bother.  Add some prints (such as `print(value1)`), and then you'll see you have another bug.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your extension is that you forgot to name your method parameter `func add(_ value: Int) -> Int? {` and add it to the someString value. Btw name Ann integer as someString is misleading and Swift is a type inferred language. There is no need to explicitly set the resulting types in most situations:

```
extension String {
    func add(_ value: Int) -> Int? {
        guard let integer = Int(self) else {
            return nil
        }
        return integer + value
    }
}
```

---

```
let value1 = "5".add(3) // value1 will equal 8
let value2 = "-2".add(1) // value2 will equal -1
let value3 = "words".add(4) // value3 will be nil
```

To silent the warning about not using the values you can simply print them.